# Why don't the dimensions in this linear regression equation match up?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, matrix

I'm going through an article on linear regression, and they give the following formula for computing estimates:

[image]

The convention is that all vectors are column vectors. So if `n` is the number of samples and `m` is the number of parameters, h<sub>w</sub>(x) has dimensions `n x 1`, w<sup>T</sup> has dimensions `1 x m`, and x has dimensions `n x m`. The problem is that these dimensions don't work out for matrix multiplication.

Where have I gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that $x$ here refers to a single datapoint with shape $m$x$1$. So $h_w(x)$ and $w^Tx$ both have shape $1$. In the case of multiple datapoints given as a matrix $X$ of shape $n$x$m$, the equation becomes:

$h_w(X) = Xw$

Comment: Indeed I think would be more consistent to have written the case in the OP as $x^Tw$. It doesn't make much sense to think of one data point as a column vector when the design matrix is inherently by convention a bunch of data as row vectors.